# Creating Random Set Values For Each Cross Join from CTE

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to load up a table with values that are generated randomly based on another table. The issue is that the result set from the final `Cross Join`, is not unique (random) for each of the rows of the final cross joined table.

---

###### Deconstructed CTE

```sql
; with MinMax as   -- Step one get the range of values for each `DetailCategoryId`
(
     select distinct DetailCategoryId,
      min(DetailId) over(partition by DetailCategoryId) as [Min] 
    , max(DetailId) over(partition by DetailCategoryId) as [Max]
    from Ref.Detail
)
```

```sql
, RandProcess as   -- Step two pick a random number between the range for each
(
    select MM.DetailCategoryId
      ,   (MM.[Min] + FLOOR(RAND() * (MM.[Max] + 1 - MM.[Min]))) as Rando
    from MinMax MM
)
```

The final step is to create a cross reference table by `Cross JOIN` that will give the set of `RandProcess` into each item. .

```sql
select  PRJ.ProjectId, RD.DetailCategoryId, RD.Rando
from info.Project PRJ
CROSS JOIN RandProcess RD
```

The issue is that each set of data in the `PRJ` table is the same. Here is the first two rows of each set `PRJ` data.

```
10000   101 7
10000   102 10
...
10001   101 7
10001   102 10
...
10002   101 7
10002   102 10
```

---

###### Question

How can I get each of the PRJs sets to be different (random) for each of the PRJ's rows?

```
10000   101 7
10000   102 10
...
10001   101 4
10001   102 11
...
10002   101 1
10002   102 14
```

---

###### Why

My goal is to insert these values into another table as test values for each of the `PRJ` data elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RAND()` is evaluated once and hence you get the same value for all rows.

You can use [`newid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to simulate a random value. [`checksum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to convert it to integer and `abs()` to return absolute value. To get into the your required minimum and maximum range

```
(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % (MM.[Max] - MM.[Min] + 1)) + MM.[Min]
```

Changes to your `RandProcess` cte

```
RandProcess as   -- Step two pick a random number between the range for each
(
    select MM.DetailCategoryId
      ,   (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % (MM.[Max] - MM.[Min] + 1)) + MM.[Min] as Rando
    from MinMax MM
)
```

Comment: Interesting, I knew that Random has only one seed, but thought that the CTE cached the first results *only* and inserted that one set over the final Cross join, which is/was the issue; it wasn't.  This suggestion which affected the set generation opened my eyes. Thx.